# JavaScript: how to get the contains of the DOM w/o ID and class?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Is it possible to get only one DOM contains by tag name without ID and class?

As you know, in HTML5 `<main>`, `<header>` and other new tags has been added, and thanks to it, to define the style of header or footer, assigning the class or id line `<div class="header">` becomes unnecessary.

E. g. I need to get the `<header>` contains, like

```
var test = document.getElementById("test");
```

by don't want to assign ID or class to header (nothing difference between `<div id="header">` and `<header id="header">`. However

```
var test = document.getElementsByTagName("header") ;
```

will not work (I mean will not save the `<header>` contains in variable value)  even if there is only one header in the page.

Anything that I can to do?

Comment: Like `document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0]`? Possible duplicate of [What does getElementsByClassName return?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10693845/1529630)

Comment: what is a DOM contains? Are you referring to a DOM node reference?

Comment: zzzzBov, I mean e. g. the contains of <header> <p>test</p> </header> is <p>test</p>. Sorry that I didn't use the professional language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('header')
```

will store all the header which is in the page in array.

```js
var test = document.getElementsByTagName("header");
alert(test[0].innerHTML);
alert(test[1].innerHTML);
```

```html
<header>first test</header>
<header>second test</header>
```

Reference link [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbytagname.asp)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to assign id or class names and want to use tag name. Then it is also fine with or without html5.

```
var test = document.getElementsByTagName("header") ;
```

You are not able to get value as test is array here , notice method name is getElementsByTagName instead of <strike>getElementByTagName</strike>.

So for getting value you need to traverse through this array and if you know it has only one header element then you can simply fetch using index.

```
     var myValue = test[0].innerHtml;
```